# Prepare for segue function using SW revealer

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a bool through a `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` using `prepareForSegue` function, but it doesn't even gives me a response.

This *code* is in my side menu `viewController` (sw_rear). I've also set an identifier on the segue and this is my *code* so far:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "registerSegue" {
        if let loginVC = segue.destination as? LoginVC {
            print("Set it as true")
            loginVC.registerActivated = true
        }
    } else {
        if let loginVC = segue.destination as? LoginVC {
            print("set it as false")
            loginVC.registerActivated = false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not receiving any output to the console with this code. Is there another good way to send data between `ViewControllers` using `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` on a *segue*?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any experience with SWRevealViewController, but looking at the code on GitHub, I can see that the SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController is not a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue (i.e. it's not a real segue), and hence, prepare will never be called.

Comment: Yeah that's true. I found out that i need to use some kind of "segue.isKind(ofClass: SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController)", but I still couldn't figure it out... Well thanks anyway!

Comment: Have you tried to check the segue with swift operator “is” : “if segue is SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController”?

Comment: I found another solution for my problem. But no I did not try `if segue.isKind(SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController`. I think it might work though